# Word for "something that is required but cannot be achieved"?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives

Alternative definition: "something that is needed but cannot be done"

**Impossible** is the best I could find, but it doesn't imply that the subject is required; only that it can't be done.

Comment: An impossible task?  Ridding the streets of crime is an impossible task, even for Batman.

Comment: For single-word request, we ask that you list which words you didn't like (based on your search for a suitable word). Failure to do so is reason to close the question as off topic. Please add your findings by editing your question. Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't meet the standards for single-word requests.

Comment: I agree that a proper answer would need a much better-phrased question, but you could try looking up *unobtainium*.

Answer (score 1):

[**Pipe dream**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/pipe_dream): an unattainable or fanciful hope or plan. [Lexico]

Comment: You should include a dictionary source/link for your definition.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context.  If you are writing about a *goal,* it might be **unattainable**.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Sisyphean](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/Sisyphean). This relates to the myth of [Sisyphus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sisyphus) and describes a task that is impossible to complete.